# Is read.table() intolerant to missing data?

Tags: r, error-handling, missing-data, read.table

I try to import the following data set into R using read.table function:

```
Gender  Age     target-TAA  Survival(mo)
1   59  IL13Ra2 6
1   63  EGFRvIII    5
2   71  IL13Ra2 12
1   67  CD133   4
2   48  EGFRvIII    10
1   78  CD133   6
1   65  IL13Ra2 5
2   65  IL13Ra2 7
1   73  EGFRvIII    2
2   78  EGFRvIII    
1   56  IL13Ra2 14
1   67  CD133   7
2   69  CD133   9
2   43  IL13Ra2 6
2   58  EGFRvIII    
1   61  CD133   3
1   60  IL13Ra2 5
2   75  EGFRvIII    13
2   66  EGFRvIII    7
```

Now, there are 3 missing data, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 5 elements
```

And this error pops up referring to different lines with missing files. How can I fix this without having to change my data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table` with `fill = TRUE`

```
df1 <- read.table('file.csv', fill = TRUE)
```